# XSL - Remove non breaking space

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

In my XSL implementation (2.0), I tried using the below statement to remove all the spaces & non breaking spaces  within a text node. It works for spaces only but not for non breaking spaces whose ASCII codes are,`&#160; &#x20; &#xA0; &#X202F; &#x2000; &#x2001; &#x2002; &#x2003; &#x2004; &#x2005; &#x2006; &#x2007; &#x2008; &#x2009; &#x200A; &#x200B; &#xFEFF;` etc. I am using SAXON processor for execution.

Current XSL code:

```
translate(normalize-space($text-nodes[1]),  ' ' , '' ))
```

How can I have them removed. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those codes are Unicode, not ASCII (for the most part), so you should probably use the [replace](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-replace) function with a [regex](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs) containing the Unicode separator [character class](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes):

```
replace($text-nodes[1], '\p{Z}+', '')
```

In more detail:

The regex `\p{Z}+` matches one or more characters that are in the "separator" category in Unicode. `\p{}` is the [category escape](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-ccescat) sequence, which matches a single character in the category specified within the curly braces. `Z` specifies the "separator" category (which includes various kinds of whitespace). `+` means "match the preceding regex one or more times". The `replace` function returns a version of its first argument with all non-overlapping substrings matching its second argument replaced with its third argument. So this returns a version of `$text-nodes[1]` with all sequences of separator characters replaced with the empty string, i.e. removed.

Comment: Are the square brackets in `'[\p{Z}]+'` necessary? Shouldn't `'\p{Z}+'` suffice?

Comment: I wasn't sure about that point when I originally wrote my answer, so I put them in to be safe. I just looked at the spec again, and you're right, the square brackets were unnecessary, so I removed them.

Comment: @wdebeaum: Could you please explain this regex expression?

Comment: @Rachel: See my edit. Also, now that I think about it, the `+` is unnecessary, but I left it in for educational value. It might also make it slightly more efficient, I don't know.

Comment: The above mentioned regex was working fine with the specified characters. I have come across few more special characters which appears as space or nothing and these characters are lieng under different unicode categories. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm , http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm  , http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm . The above mentioned categories have few characters which appears as space or nothing. How do i ignore these characters from the above familes which appears as a space or nothing?

Comment: The three categories you link to are `Zs`, `Cf`, and `Cc`. I think `Zs` is included in `Z`, so if you wanted to match all of the characters in the other two categories as well, you could put their `\p{}` escapes inside square brackets, like so: `[\p{Z}\p{Cf}\p{Cc}]`. If you just want specific characters from those categories, you can include entity references for them. For example, to match separators, plus "zero width space" and "null", use this regex: `[\p{Z}&#x200B;&#x0000;]`.