# XSLT Regex in replace()

Tags: regex, xslt

I am having an issue when trying to replace multiple spaces in a piece of text within an XSLT transform. I feel like I am overlooking something simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

**Simple example:**

```
<para>Doors 1 (<extref targetid="REF1034248349404" id="abc-123"/>) and 2  (<extref targetid="REF1034248370394" id="xyz-123"/>) closed, for temporary installation see <xref xrefid="def-123"/>
</para>
```

**Simple Template:**

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <p>Text as is</p>
    <xsl:for-each select="text()/normalize-space()">
        <text><xsl:value-of select="."/></text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <p>Text with '\s+' replaced with '*'</p>
    <xsl:for-each select="text()/normalize-space()">
        <text><xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s+', '*')"/></text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<p>Text as is</p>
<text>Doors 1 (</text>
<text>) and 2  (</text>
<text>) closed, for temporary installation see</text>
<text/>
<p>Text with '\s+' replaced with '*'</p>
<text>Doors*1*(</text>
<text>)*and*2*(</text>
<text>)*closed,*for*temporary*installation*see</text>
<text/>
```

**Actual output:**

```
<p>Text as is</p>
<text>Doors 1 (</text>
<text>) and 2  (</text>
<text>) closed, for temporary installation see</text>
<text/>
<p>Text with '\s+' replaced with '*'</p>
<text>Doors*1*(</text>
<text>)*and*2* (</text>
<text>)*closed,*for*temporary*installation*see</text>
<text/>
```

Notice the extra space in the second `<text>` element. What could the reason be that '\s+' is not finding the multiple (I believe 2) spaces after the '2' character?

As always, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue. I get your expected output using Saxon-HE 9.9.1.7 in oXygen.

Comment: I am on Saxon PE 11.4 in oXygen. Been driving me nuts since Friday. Going to try it with the EE and HE versions and see if I get any different results.

Answer (score 3):

After a new apporach to debugging it, I found my problem. I took my samples and ran them with Saxon via Python (saxoncee). Upon running my original XSL and printing the output to the terminal with lxml, I found the culprit:

```
<test>
 <p>Text as is</p>
 <text>Doors 1 (</text>
 <text>) and 2 &#160;(</text>
 <text>) closed, for temporary installation see</text>
 <text/>
 <p>Text with '\s+' replaced with '*'</p>
 <text>Doors*1*(</text>
 <text>)*and*2*&#160;(</text>
 <text>)*closed,*for*temporary*installation*see</text>
 <text/>
</test>
```

There is a non-breaking space character in the source. I changed the XSL as below:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <p>Text as is</p>
    <xsl:for-each select="text()/normalize-space()">
        <text><xsl:value-of select="."/></text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <p>Text with '\s+' replaced with '*'</p>
    <xsl:for-each select="text()/normalize-space()">
        <text><xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\p{Z}+', '*')"/></text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And now get the desired output:

```
<test>
 <p>Text as is</p>
 <text>Doors 1 (</text>
 <text>) and 2 &#160;(</text>
 <text>) closed, for temporary installation see</text>
 <text/>
 <p>Text with '\s+' replaced with '*'</p>
 <text>Doors*1*(</text>
 <text>)*and*2*(</text>
 <text>)*closed,*for*temporary*installation*see</text>
 <text/>
</test>
```

Got some help from this post:
[XSL - Remove non breaking space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639613/xsl-remove-non-breaking-space)